# Как разделить строку на подстроки?

Tags: python, строки

У меня есть вот такая СТРОКА:

{'4000000000111':'Бумага А4', '4000000002111':'OIL GEL PEN (Sigma)', '4000000003111':'Календарь для кармана'}

Мне нужно ее изменить до следующего вида:

```
4000000000111 Бумага А4
4000000002111 OIL GEL PEN (Sigma)
4000000003111 Календарь для кармана
```

Я написала вот такой код:

```
k="{'4000000000111':'Бумага А4', '4000000002111':'OIL GEL PEN (Sigma)', 
'4000000003111':'Календарь для кармана'}"
l = []

for i in k:
   l.append(i)#здесь я разделяла это на отдельные элементы'{', "'", '4', '0', '0', '0'...
 
l1 = []
for j in l:
   if j in "'{},":
      del j
   else:
      l1.append(j)#здесь удаляла ненужное и добавляла в список['4', '0', '0', '0', '0',

new = ''.join(l1)
#здесь получила вот такое 4000000000111:Бумага А4
m = []
v = new.split()
for h in v:
   m.append(h.replace(':', ' '))
print(*m)#здесь заменяла : на пробел
```

Я получила вот такое:

4000000000111 Бумага А4 4000000002111 OIL GEL PEN (Sigma) 4000000003111 Календарь для кармана

Я пробовала писать в конце print(*m, sep ='\n'), но я не получала желаемого результата

Как разбить эту строчку на подстроки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полагаю, что более правильным решением будет работать с JSON через встроенный пакет.

```
import json
data_str = "{'4000000000111':'Бумага А4', '4000000002111':'OIL GEL PEN (Sigma)', '4000000003111':'Календарь для кармана'}".replace("'", '"')
# здесь пришлось заменить с помощью метода replace одинарные кавычки на двойные, потому что так требует формат JSON'а

data = json.loads(data_str) # так мы парсим строку, в итоге получаем dict.

for k in data: # в цикле перебираются ключи из dict'а
    print(k, data[k]) # выводим пары ключ и значение
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, я еще не учила json, теперь буду знать, что такое существует и выучу это, и углублю свои знания. Еще раз спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @st040506, Молодчина. Лайк за упорные старания

Comment: В качестве дополнения к ответу `print(*['%s %s' % item for item in data.items()], sep='\n')`

Comment: @Namerek, красиво, но слишком усложнено :D

Comment: @SergeyK., Не спорю, топикстартеру не по зубам, потому и как ответ не пилил. В данном случае Вашего выше крыши )

Comment: @Namerek, моего ответа не только более чем достаточно, но он и более рациональный, бзе лишних формирований списка таплов, форматирования, распаковки, запаковки в лист и снова распаковки, короче, только красиво, но не эффективно))

Answer (score 3):

ваша строка это по сути уже готовый словарь, извлечь его из строки можно функцией `eval` таким образом:

```
k="{'4000000000111':'Бумага А4', '4000000002111':'OIL GEL PEN (Sigma)', '4000000003111':'Календарь для кармана'}"

for key,v in eval(k).items():
    print(key, v)
'''
4000000000111 Бумага А4
4000000002111 OIL GEL PEN (Sigma)
4000000003111 Календарь для кармана
```

но есть мнение, что использование `eval` не вполне безопасно (имеется в виду вычисление строк полученных из ненадежных источников). Для безопасного вычисления строк из ненадежных источников есть такой способ:

```
from ast import literal_eval

for key,v in literal_eval(k).items():
    print(key, v)
'''
4000000000111 Бумага А4
4000000002111 OIL GEL PEN (Sigma)
4000000003111 Календарь для кармана
```